# How to add ```Context``` with routes set up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-context

I want to add the `searchContext` context in my App.js so that my `Navbar` an `Results` components have access to the variables in it. How would I do this with my routes set up? I tried to just add with with them but that didn't work. This is the code.

```
<Router>
        // Where does <searchContext.Provider> go?
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/results'>
              <Route path='/results/:value' element={<Results />} />            
              {/*<Route path='/results/:value/:slot' element={<Slot />}*/}
            </Route>
            // Another route that has nothing to do with searchContext
         </Routes>
    </Router>
```

Edit: Added "// Another route that has nothing to do with searchContext"

Comment: Is there any relevant reason for not wrapping the entire router inside the context?

Comment: Just thought it's not good to have global code because I am going to have other routes set up that have nothing to do with the searchContext.

Comment: Context is "global" - if you want access to the context inside your components you need to wrap them inside the context provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i were you i would just wrap the all thing with the provider as long as its not to heavy.

Comment: Hey what about if I add other other routes set up that have nothing to do with the searchContext.

Comment: if you really want only the necessary components to have accsess you could separately wrap them, a provider for each one of them.

Comment: If other routes have nothing to do with context, just dont bother using it inside them. since by using it inside a component its how a component actually subscribes to it

Answer (score 0):

Hellow, this goes with general understanding of context Api,
now the structure of your folders is your choice but i'll be very brief here

```
//on your context file searchContext.js
import {useState,createContext} from 'react';

export const SearchContext = createContext(null);
export const ContextProvider = props => {
  const [search,setSearch] = useState(null);
  

 return <SearchContext.Provider value = {{search,setSearch}}>
        {children>
        </SearchContext.Provider>
}

//now on your route.js
import { ContextProvider} from '../your/path/file';
....
<Router>
        // Where does <searchContext.Provider> go?
        <ContextProvider>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
            <Route path='/results'>
              <Route path='/results/:value' element={<Results />} />            
              {/*<Route path='/results/:value/:slot' element={<Slot />}*/}
            </Route>
            // Another route that has nothing to do with searchContext
         </Routes>
      </ContextProvider>
    </Router>
```

Comment: Just wrapping a `<Navbar/>` and `<Routes/>` with it so it'll be accessible to both